# Curl redirect,, not working?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using the following code:

```
$agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9) Gecko/2008052906 Firefox/3.0';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.example.com");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $output;
```

But it redirects to like this:

```
http://localhost/aide.do?sht=_aide_cookies_
```

Instead of to the URL page.

Can anyone help me solve my problem, please?

Comment: If you indent your code by four spaces, it'll be more readable.

Answer (score 14):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

http://docs.php.net/function.curl-setopt says:

> CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION
> TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set).

Comment: +1 I love it when I find exactly what I'm looking for on SO with a single search

Answer (score 8):

If it's up to URL redirection only then see the following code, I've documented it for you so you can use it easily & directly, you've two main cURL options control URL redirection (CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION/CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS):

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");

// The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9) Gecko/2008052906 Firefox/3.0");

// TRUE to include the header in the output.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

// TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set).
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// The maximum amount of HTTP redirections to follow. Use this option alongside CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);

// grab URL and pass it to the output variable
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

// Print the output from our variable to the browser
print_r($output);
```

The above code handles the URL redirection issue, but it doesn't deal with cookies (your localhost URL seems to be dealing with cookies). If you wish to deal with cookies from the cURL resource, then you may have to give the following cURL options a look:
CURLOPT_COOKIE
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR

For further details please follow the following link:
http://docs.php.net/function.curl-setopt